# Confused about Haskell polymorphic types

Tags: haskell

I have defined a function :

```
gen :: a -> b
```

So just trying to provide a simple implementation :

```
gen 2 = "test"
```

But throws error :

```
gen.hs:51:9:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘b’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for gen :: a -> b at gen.hs:50:8
    Relevant bindings include gen :: a -> b (bound at gen.hs:51:1)
    In the expression: "test"
    In an equation for ‘gen’: gen 2 = "test"
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

So my function is not correct. Why is `a` not typed as Int and `b` not typed as String ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a very common misunderstanding.

The key thing to understand is that if you have a variable in your type signature, then *the caller* gets to decide what type that is, *not you!*

So you cannot say "this function returns type `x`" and then just return a `String`; your function actually has to be able to return *any possible type* that the caller may ask for. If I ask your function to return an `Int`, it has to return an `Int`. If I ask it to return a `Bool`, it has to return a `Bool`.

Your function *claims* to be able to return any possible type, but *actually* it only ever returns `String`. So it doesn't do what the type signature claims it does. Hence, a compile-time error.

A lot of people apparently misunderstand this. In (say) Java, you can say "this function returns `Object`", and then your function can return anything it wants. So the *function* decides what type it returns. In Haskell, the *caller* gets to decide what type is returned, not the function.

**Edit:** Note that the type you're written, `a -> b`, is impossible. No function can *ever* have this type. There's no way a function can construct a value of type `b` out of thin air. The only way this can work is if some of the inputs also involve type `b`, or if `b` belongs to some kind of typeclass which allows value construction.

For example:

```
head :: [x] -> x
```

The return type here is `x` ("any possible type"), but the input type also mentions `x`, so this function is possible; you just have to return one of the values that was in the original list.

Similarly, `gen :: a -> a` is a perfectly valid function. But the only thing it can do is return it's input unchanged (i.e., what the `id` function does).

This property of type signatures telling you what a function does is a very useful and powerful property of Haskell.

Comment: The `Object` type in Java is not the same as a universally quantified type variable in Haskell. The `Object` type is the [top type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_type) of Java whereas a universally quantified type variable is the [bottom type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type) in Haskell. Hence, the `Object` type in Java is actually equivalent to `forall r. (forall a. a -> r) -> r` in Haskell where `a` is the existentially quantified variable.

Comment: Oops. I misread your answer. I thought that you were saying that the `Object` type in Java is equivalent to the bottom type in Haskell. Nevertheless, you can have a function that returns an existential type in Haskell. Thus, technically it is possible for a function in Haskell to choose its own return type.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid so what is a valid implementation of 'gen' given I cannot return any type other than 'b'? I fail to see how this is polymorphic, even though I know it is...

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid cool, think I see things a little clearer now : data List t = E | C t (List t)
 deriving Show gen :: a -> List a
gen a = C a E

Comment: @blue-sky There are some ways to implement `gen`, but most of them are useless. For example `gen x = gen x` works (and never successfully produces a result), so does `gen x = unsafeCoerce x`, which actually may produce a valid result, but the function doesn't have "unsafe" in its name for no reason (basically it's like a `reinterpret_cast` in C++ or addressof + cast + dereference in C).

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid "the caller gets to decide what type that is, not you!" what is the caller in this context ? Is the caller not the code that invokes the function, which is me ?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid so "the caller gets to decide what type that is, not you!" is false as I do not get to decide what that type is ? The type is "a" and I do not get to decide what the type is, it must be type a, therefore the caller does not get to decide the type ?

Comment: @blue-sky The caller is the expression that calls (applies) the function. The fact that you wrote both expressions is irrelevant.

Comment: [`Unsafe.Coerce`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Unsafe-Coerce.html#v:unsafeCoerce) is `a -‭> b` ;)

Answer (score 7):

`gen :: a -> b` does not mean "for some type `a` and some type `b`, `foo` must be of type `a -> b`", it means "for *any* type `a` and *any* type `b`, `foo` must be of type `a -> b`".

to motivate this: If the type checker sees something like `let x :: Int = gen "hello"`, it sees that `gen` is used as `String -> Int` here and then looks at `gen`'s type to see whether it can be used that way. The type is `a -> b`, which can be specialized to `String -> Int`, so the type checker decides that this is fine and allows this call. That is since the function is declared to have type `a -> b`, the type checker allows you to call the function with any type you want and allows you to use the result as any type you want.

However that clearly does not match the definition you gave the function. The function knows how to handle numbers as arguments - nothing else. And likewise it knows how to produce strings as its result - nothing else. So clearly it should not be possible to call the function with a string as its argument or to use the function's result as an Int. So since the type `a -> b` would allow that, it's clearly the wrong type for that function.

Answer (score 2):

Your type signature `gen :: a -> b` is stating, that your function can work for *any* type a (and provide *any* type b the *caller* of the function demands).

Besides the fact that such a function is hard to come by, the line `gen 2 = "test"` tries to return a `String` which very well may not be what the caller demands.

Comment: What do you mean by "hard to come by"? It's impossible to "normally" create a function of the type `a -> b`. The only function of the type `a -> b` is `let f x = f x` or a variant thereof such as `let f x = undefined` or `let f x = error "This function is pointless."`. There's no useful function of the type `a -> b`.

Comment: Well, except `unsafeCoerce`.

Answer (score 1):

Excellent answers.  Given your profile, however, you seem to know Java, so I think it's valuable to connect this to Java as well.

Java offers two kinds of polymorphism:

1. **Subtype polymorphism:** e.g., every type is a subtype of `java.lang.Object`
2. **Generic polymorphism:** e.g., in the `List<T>` interface.

Haskell's type variables are a version of (2).  Haskell doesn't really have a version of (1).

One way to think of generic polymorphism is in terms of *templates* (which is what C++ people call them): a type that has a type variable parameter is a template that can be *specialized* into a variety of *monomorphic* types.  So for example, the interface `List<T>` is a template for constructing monomorphic interfaces like `List<String>`, `List<List<String>>` and so on, all of which have the same structure but differ only because the type variable `T` gets replaced uniformly throughout the signatures with the instantiation type.

The concept that "the caller chooses" that several responders have mentioned here is basically a friendly way of referring to instantiation.  In Java, for example, the most common point where the type variable gets "chosen" is when an object is instantiated:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Second common point is that a subtype of a generic type may instantiate the supertype's variables:

```
class MyFunction implements Function<Integer, String> {
    public String apply(Integer i) { ... }
}
```

Third one is methods that allow the caller to instantiate a variable that's not a parameter of its enclosing type:

```
/**
 * Visitor-pattern style interface for a simple arithmetical language
 * abstract syntax tree.
 */
interface Expression {
    // The caller of `accept` implicitly chooses which type `R` is,
    // by supplying a `Visitor<R>` with `R` instantiated to something
    // of its choice.
    <R> accept(Expression.Visitor<R> visitor);

    static interface Visitor<R> {
        R constant(int i);
        R add(Expression a, Expression b);
        R multiply(Expression a, Expression b);
    }
}
```

In Haskell, instantiation is carried out implicitly by the type inference algorithm.  In any expression where you use `gen :: a -> b`, type inference will infer what types need to be instantiated for `a` and `b`, given the context in which `gen` is used.  So basically, "caller chooses" means that any code that uses `gen` controls the types to which `a` and `b` will be instantiated; if I write `gen [()]`, then I'm implicitly instantiating `a` to `[()]`.  The error here means that your type declaration says that `gen [()]` is allowed, but your equation `gen 2 = "test"` implies that it's not.

Comment: +1 thanks, I sort of "get it", it seems to me that once a generic type parameter is used the operations of the function are extremely limited, as cannot subtype the generic type to more specific behavior. I've just started on my Haskell journey so hopefully will make more sense as I go deeper.

Answer (score 0):

In Haskell, type variables are implicitly quantified, but we can make this explicit:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

gen :: forall a b . a -> b
gen x = ????
```

The "forall" is really just a type level version of a lambda, often written Λ. So `gen` is a function taking three arguments: a type, bound to the name `a`, another type, bound to the name `b`, and a value of type `a`, bound to the name `x`. When your function is called, it is called with those three arguments. Consider a saner case:

```
fst :: (a,b) -> a
fst (x1,x2) = x1
```

This gets translated to

```
fst :: forall (a::*) (b::*) . (a,b) -> a
fst = /\ (a::*) -> /\ (b::*) -> \ (x::(a,b)) ->
   case x of
      (x1, x2) -> x1
```

where `*` is the type (often called a *kind*) of normal concrete types. If I call `fst (3::Int, 'x')`, that gets translated into

```
fst Int Char (3Int, 'x')
```

where I use `3Int` to represent specifically the `Int` version of `3`. We could then calculate it as follows:

```
fst Int Char (3Int, 'x')
=
(/\ (a::*) -> /\ (b::*) -> \(x::(a,b)) -> case x of (x1,x2) -> x1) Int Char (3Int, 'x')
=
(/\ (b::*) -> \(x::(Int,b)) -> case x of (x1,x2) -> x1) Char (3Int, 'x')
=
(\(x::(Int,Char)) -> case x of (x1,x2) -> x1) (3Int, x)
=
case (3Int,x) of (x1,x2) -> x1
=
3Int
```

Whatever types I pass in, as long as the value I pass in matches, the `fst` function will be able to produce something of the required type. If you try to do this for `a->b`, you will get stuck.